# How to validate a name using ignore in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to validate a The Units name. the unit name should be unique by branch wise. I write a code using rule and its working quite fine in creating but its not working on updating.
Here what i have tried

```
$units=Unit::where('name',$request->name)->where('branch_id',$request->branch)
            ->pluck('branch_id');
Rule::unique('units','name')->where(function ($query) use ($units){
                     $query->whereIn('branch_id', $units);
                })->ignore($request->unit_id,'name')
```

Comment: You are writing this code in request file?

Comment: no, in controller above the saving process

Comment: what is `unit_id` since you also have `id` on that table?

Comment: If you got the answer please share it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Rule::unique('units','name')->where(function ($query) use ($units, $request){
       $query->where('branch_id', $units);
  })->ignore($request->unit_id)
```

Comment: @TanvirAhmed I have an updated answer. If `$request->unit_id` is primary key like `id`.

Comment: actually i am very sorry, my request parameter is seem something wrong thats why i faced the problem, sorry again

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Rule::unique('units','name')->where(function ($query) use ($request){
           $query->where('branch_id', $request->branch);
      })->ignore($request->id)   // or ->ignore($request->unit_id) if you get unit_id from form
```

Comment: the primary key is id

Comment: Updated answer. if your primary key as id no need to write column name in ignore

Comment: actually i am very sorry, my request parameter is seem something wrong thats why i faced the problem, sorry again

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `unit_id` is the key you are trying to do the ignore for:

```
Rule::unique('units', 'name')
    ->where('branch_id', (int) $request->branch)
    ->ignore((int) $request->unit_id, 'unit_id')
```

This simplifies it a little. Ideally no input directly from the user would be passed to the `ignore` method at all, but at least the cast to int, `(int)`, is limiting it to just a number. The warning from the Laravel Docs:

> "You should never pass any user controlled request input into the `ignore` method. Instead, you should only pass a system generated unique ID such as an auto-incrementing ID or UUID from an Eloquent model instance. Otherwise, your application will be vulnerable to an SQL injection attack." [Laravel 6.x Docs - Validation - Rules - `unique`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-unique)

To avoid this we can find a model then pass that to the `ignoreModel` method:

```
$unit = Unit::where('unit_id', $request->unit_id)->firstOrFail();

Rule::unique('units', 'name')
    ->where('branch_id', (int) $request->branch)
    ->ignoreModel($unit);
```

Comment: actually i am very sorry, my request parameter is seem something wrong thats why i faced the problem, sorry again